# How to solve "Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')" and "Can't determine project language from files."

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure-functions

I had a project that was running fine in Visual Studio. It also runs fine for QA testers who were using Visual Studio Code.

Long story short, my old computer was destroyed, and I am trying to get the project running on a new computer. The first problem I ran into was, of course, that when I cloned the project I didn't have a local.settings.json file anymore. So I created it, but I couldn't get the application to recognize it was there. I compared with other projects and made modifications to the .csproj file to make sure everything was equal but to no avail. Then I added a line in the Startup.cs file to `.AddJsonFile("local.settings.json")`. Doing this didn't make the messages that it couldn't determine the project language go away but it did add a new error that `Value cannot be null (Parameter 'provider'). I will mention, also, that I didn't need to specifically add the file in Startup previously.

Oh, before I added the `.AddJsonFile()` line, it was telling me "The 'FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME' setting is required. By adding that line I was able to exchange that error for the incredibly ambiguous `Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')` error.

If I was trying to run with VS Code, I would add appropriate commands to let it know the language; but I don't know how to do that in Visual Studio where I don't run it from a command line but just click play. And, I don't think that's the main issue anyway.

So this is a two question question:

1. How can I specify the language in Visual Studio when I'm just clicking play as opposed to entering a command in a terminal where I could add parameters?
2. How the heck do I troubleshoot the `Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')` error??? I've seen this error a few times now, and it has always been becuase I tried to update some nuget package. Each time this has happened, after investigating, I've always ended up just reverting the package back to what it was before because I couldn't solve the problem. This has been very frustrating as one of the packages I'm using is an obsolete Serilog package... but I simply can't figure out how to get past this error. There are some threads about it in various places, but after wasting many hours it appears that this is an ambiguous message and that I haven't yet mastered the skills needed to properly troubleshoot it. So... please help!

[image: Error]